# it is possible to chooce the mipmap size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mipmap

When I choose a mipmap to display, it displays the big size mimap.
I want to know if it is possible to choose the small mipmap.
I want to specify the size of mipmap to display.

Thank you.

Comment: You can set ImageView height and width.

Comment: I once asked a similar question here a while back (now deleted). Sadly, no you can't.. You can't go beyond the fixed size specified. Sorry ;-)

Comment: actually, android system chooses one depends on screen density. so, I think you can't do that :(

Comment: Thank you I can solve my problem now !

Comment: The Only best way is to generated mipmap image and give it to the image view with the size that you need !!!!! 
God Bye